# CSS transtition on both text and background

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions, transition

I'm designing a simple slide-in menu using JavaScript, HTML and CSS on a mobile device

```
<div class="menu">division
     <ul>unordered list
          <li>list item 1</li>
          <li>list item 2</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    background: #111;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; 
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.menu.act {
    position: absolute;
    background: #111;
    width: 67%;
}
```

(A simpple bit of JavaScript code changes the menu's class to "menu act") 

 The question is, why is only the black background sliding in from the left, while the text inside HTML elements stays on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't **moving/sliding** the `ul` at all, just changing the width.

The `ul` has no width and so no background can show. The text overflows the zero-width element which is why it is still visible.

Then when you expand the width the background becomes visible.

I've switched this to a `:hover` to demonstrate.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  background: #111;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  color: white;
}
.menu:hover {
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  width: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Instead, try leaving the width as 67% and adjust the position..something like this.

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -67%;
  width: 67%;
  background: #111;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  color: white;
}
body:hover .menu {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

OR with a **transform** then the "positioning" would be automatic.

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 67%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: #111;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  color: white;
}
body:hover .menu {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Spot on answer!   For further understanding: In the later case you mooved the <ul> element into the background (out of the screen)?    Also, what exactly do you mean by "The text overflows the zero-width element " - how do I know what form (line breaks, etc.) the text will take once it overflows?   Much appreciated

Comment: Overflowing text will take the smallest width it can usually.